# Bootstrap responsive css and/or viewport issue/bug on rotation of a device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, rotation, responsive-design, mobile-website

I've currently got a problem in my website http://www.peterfox.me, when ever viewing it with a mobile device, (iPhone, Nexus 4) rotating the screen seems to screw up the size of the body/html, is this a bug in Bootstrap's responsive CSS? or is it a key problem in my site? Or even just a general problem with mobile browsers?

The symptom of is generally you go from portrait to landscape or start in landscape and rotating to portrait leaves the page being viewed as if it was still the width of landscape proportions when in fact it's in portrait leaving a gap, please see [screen shot before rotation](http://i.imgur.com/oz6OEvl) and [screen shot after rotation](http://i.imgur.com/CjThvW9) for a better understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fixed it in the end with

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Your meta viewport should be like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Try removing the extra properties from your meta tag.

Comment: Nope, just put this into effect and it still keeps the problem but thank you for your suggestion, it would make sense to be related to that

Comment: This led me to the solution as the overflow-x from @Sly did not change the issue (iPad 4, iOS 6.1, both Safari and Cordova 3.0). My viewport meta also included `user-scalable=no` and `height=device-height`. Once I removed the height, it worked. (I kept the user-scalble for faster clicks).

Comment: @JeffCollier You can use `user-scalable=no` if you really want to, but I wouldn't really recommend it. Some users may not see the contents without scaling in.